# run setState after others setStates are completed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const onDrawerClose = () => {
    setCloseDrawer1(false);
    setCloseDrawer2(false);
    setData(null);
  };
```

When some fields in the data are empty I show error message. It works good but when I close the sidebar, while it's closing I can see for 1second or so this error message since here in the code above we set data to null, how I can properly run the third setState after the previous two are completed?

Comment: There isn't a problem in this code. Is there some animation happening? Where does the 1 second delay come from?

Comment: Drawer is closing, there is no problem with the code, I just wondering how to run third setState only after the previous are completed? Because when I close the sidebar it probably takes up to 1 second to close and since these 3 setStates are running in parallel the data is null hence I show error message

Comment: So you want to `setData(null)` after 1 second because of a close animation?

Comment: I want it after I closed the drawer, when drawer is false it is closed

Answer (score 0):

You can listen when the **draw1** and **draw2** are closed using an useEffect like:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(!closeDrawer1 && !closeDrawer2) {
       setData(null);
   }
}, [closeDrawer1, closeDrawer2])
```

If there is an animation when drawers are closing you can set data after the animation happen using **setTimeout**.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const drawerCloseTimeout = 1000; // 1 sec
    if(!closeDrawer1 && !closeDrawer2) {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => setData(null), drawerCloseTimeout);
        return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
}, [closeDrawer1, closeDrawer2]);
```